# How to modify the height of status bar?

Tags: android, android-widget

Can I modify the height of the status bar? If yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean with status bar? The title bar on top of your app? Why have you used the tag widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'status bar' is called 'notification bar' and is not part of your app, but system-wide. You cannot change the height, you can only hide it completely in your app by setting your app to fullscreen (via Theme: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`).